# PHP flush don't work

Tags: php, flush

I'm trying to get PHP flush working for 2 hours, i can't make it work, in localhost it work, but when i drag it on server it stop working.
The code is this:

```
<?php
  ob_implicit_flush(true);
  ob_end_flush();
  for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo $i.'<br>';
    sleep(1);
  }
?>
```

I tried a lot of other versions, but all the version i fond work only on localhost (as this), but not on my server, i read somewhere that it would be fixed changing some lines on the php.ini file, but i'm using an Aruba hosting windows domain, so i can't edit the php.ini, how can i do?

**Update:** I tried it on others two free hosting serice, and it work on them, it's just my main hosting services that do problem: what can it be?
**Update:** Since a lot of script i found use ini_set I tried to check values that they set, i don't know if they can be useful:
`session.use_trans_sid 0
 output_buffering 4096
 zlib.output_compression Off`

Comment: Your server may have a caching front-end to reduce a load.

Comment: Are you calling ob_start()? http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: I tried even with ob_start and ob_flush with flush, but the problem  maybe that my server have some integrated buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but only in a default apache environment:

```
<?php
ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
if( !ob_get_level() ){ ob_start(); }
else { ob_end_clean(); ob_start(); }
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  //For Nginx we have to reach minimum  buffer size, 
  //so if it is not enough increment output
  echo str_pad( $i . '<br>', 1024 + 10, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT ); 
  flush();
  ob_flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

Nginx needs more configurations:

usually in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
gzip off;
proxy_buffering off;
fastcgi_buffer_size 1k;       #set buffer to 1k
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
fastcgi_buffers 128 1k;       #set max buffer size to 1k + 128*1k
```

Comment: this may work, but i'm using a windows hosting so this folder doesen't exist :(

Comment: In windows don't worry about nginx configuration, try to increment the output bytes, try to reach 4096 bytes for row. `echo str_pad( $i . '<br>', 4 * 1024 + 10, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT );`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php

  ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);

  ob_implicit_flush(true);
  ob_end_flush();
  for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo $i.'<br>';
    sleep(1);
  }
?>
```

Or check:
[php implicit_flush command not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100929/php-implicit-flush-command-not-working-correctly)

Comment: Im not doubting that this could work, I am just not sure how?

Comment: Not sure either, stumbled upon it while googling. I've edited my post with a link to another StackOverflow question. You should try that out.

Comment: Grasping at straws is not the way to answer a question on SO.

Comment: It's hard to reproduce the problem though. So I can't test it.